# TABLE DROP statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to drop a table that I created in SQL Server.  I typed the command as follows:
DROP TABLE [Exercise2].

I received the following error message:
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 1
Cannot drop the table 'Exercise2', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I have dropped multiple tables trying to clean out my database, but this one will not drop and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are you sure the table exists?   And didn't get dropped already?   Does SELECT * FROM [Exercise2] give you an error message?

Comment: Do you have a DROP TABLE privilege?